# MySQL UPDATE vs INSERT and DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am working on a web app project and there is a rather large html form that needs to have its data stored in a table. The form and insert are already done but my client wants to be able to load the saved data back into the HTML form and be able to change it, again, this is no problem, but I came across a question when going to do the update, would it be appropriate to just keep the insert query and then delete the old row if it was an edit?

Basically, what already happens is when the form is submitted all of the data is put into a table using INSERT, I also have a flag called edit that contains the primary key ID if the data is for an existing field being updated. I can handle the update function two ways:

a) Create an actual update query with all the fields/data set and use an if/else to decide whether to run the update or insert query.

b) Do the insert every time but add a single line to DELETE WHERE row=editID after the insert is successful.

Since the Delete would only happen if the INSERT was successful I don't run the risk of deleting the data without inserting, thus losing the data, but since INSERT/DELETE is two queries, would it be less efficient than just using an if/else to decide whether to run an insert or update?

There is a second table that uses the auto-increment id as a foreign key, but this table has to be updated every time the form is submitted, so if I delete the row in table A, I will also be deleting the associated rows from table b. This seems like it would be bad programming practice, so  I am leaning towards option a) anyway, but it is very tempting just to use the single line option. The DELETE would basically be as follows. Would this in fact be bad programming practice? Aside from conventions, are there any reasons why this is a "never do that!" type of code?

```
    if ($insertFormResults) {
        $formId = mysql_insert_id();
        echo "Your form was saved successfully.";
        if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
            $query = "DELETE FROM registerForm WHERE id='$_POST[edit]'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [MySQL's LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) will give you the autoincrement value, which you can then use in an UPDATE statement.  Deleting will run the autoincrement value up unnecessarily, besides impact to referential integrity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst the INSERT/DELETE option would work perfectly well I'd recommend against it as:

- Unless you bundle the INSERT/DELETE
  up into a single transaction, or
  better yet encapsulate the
  INSERT/DELETE up into a stored
  procedure you do run the theoretical
  risk of accumulating duplicates. If
  you use a SP or a transaction you're
  just effectively rewriting the UPDATE
  statement which is obviously
  inefficient and moreover will give
  rise to a few WTF raised eyebrows
  later by anyone maintaining your
  code.
- Although it doesn't sound like an
  issue in your case you are
  potentially impacting referential
  integrity should you need that. 
  Furthermore you are loosing the
  rather useful ability to easily
  retrieve records in creation order.
- Probably not a great consideration on
  a small application, but you are
  going to end up with a seriously
  fragmented database fairly quickly
  which will slow data retrieval.

Comment: It's a database for Freshman Orientation at my University, so minimum of 1000 new entries each year, depending on incoming class size. I wasn't considering the fragmentation, and that would definitely cause issues down the road.

Comment: @awestover89 - makes sense to do things properly then. Personally with these things I'm usually motivated by the first one - *not* giving whoever comes after me a WTF moment. Your reputation is important and although no matter how you code they'll be someone who comes along later who will criticise you (maybe because they do odd things themselves) it's better not to give them the excuse by using unusual constructions for standard operations.

Comment: I agree with Cruachan. UPDATE essentially **is** "insert a new one and delete the old one," except that 1) it's an atomic operation, 2) it keeps the same ID 3) it's the way MySQL natively understands this and 4) it's the way everyone else does it. 3 and 4 are both important. MySQL will be optimized best for doing things the standard way. And absolutely the next programmer will understand "update" more quickly. Try to only do things in a non-standard way when you have a clear reason for it and can explain that in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Update is only one round trip to the server, which is more efficient.  Unless you have a reason that involves the possibility of bad data, always default to using an UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that doing the delete is pointless, if you run an update in MySql it will only update the record if it is different that what is stored already, is there some reason why you would need to do a delete instead. I usually use a case(switch) to catch update/delete calls from the user,

```
<?php
switch (action) {

case "delete" :
block of coding;
if the condition equals value1;
break;

case "edit" :
block of coding;
if the condition equals value2;
break;

}
?>
```